# Tablelayout panel - draw outer borders and cell

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

I have 3 rows in my TableLayoutPanel and I want to draw borders around It like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this ?

I tried this, but It doesn't draw outer borders of 1st row:

```
 If (e.Column = 0 And e.Row = 1) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.FromArgb(94, 94, 94)), e.CellBounds)
        End If
```

Output of this code is :

[image]

Any help much appreciated !

Comment: didn't understood your need correctly. You want to draw rectangle comprising of 2 columns and 2 rows. Am I correct? Your code draws rectangle for only one of the cell while your attached image shows 2 cells are bounded with red rectangle.

Comment: @MukulVarshney, my need is first image. second image is output of my current code. Red colour represents border.

Comment: output of your code shows border around 4 cells, while i used your code, for me it shows border across only 1 cell. Also, how to know you need border across which cells.

Comment: @MukulVarshney, sorry, you were right, I posted wrong images. I have only 1 column, thanks for pointing out. See my edited question now, this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the `e.Row = 1` part. Remember that the first row is index 0.

Try this:

```
If (e.Column = 0 And e.Row = 0) Then
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.FromArgb(94, 94, 94)), e.CellBounds)
End If
```

Comment: thanks for response but that is obviously not working, It just creates border around top cell. I know that first row is index 0.

Comment: Ok, that was an obvious mistake. I noticed that you draw only on one Cell. You should take the current cell bounds, the next cell bounds and create a new rectangle from the sum of the two.

Comment: yes I know that, but I can't figure out how, I tried many things so far.

Comment: Google for it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellpaintingeventargs.cellbounds(v=vs.110).aspx